Bulk updating View Settings Inheritance
I have a custom view that is set for a client folder list (Long list of folders each its own client) I need to apply this view only to Clients folders not any deeper in the folder structure.
This means the view must only apply to the client folders "list" but once you click into a client folder it defaults to the standard view. (All documents)
For example: Documents > Clients Where the custom view must apply > Company A; Company B; Etc...
The reason I am doing is the custom view I have created will group the client folders via a unique classification, this will make it easier to search for items as there is nearly 400 client folders in the Client location.
The Ask:
The only way I can see this being possible is by setting all folders in Client to no but I need to do this in bulk. Most Googling only tells me how to break permission inheritance in bulk not the specific View Settings Inheritance I am looking for.

Unfortunately, SharePoint does not support applying views conditionally based on folder depth directly via the UI or settings.
You could experiment with a combination of filtering and scripting to manage this.
Step 1: Create Views

Top-Level Folders View:

Go to your document library.
Create a view (e.g., ClientFoldersView) that groups and displays the top-level folders as needed.
Filter this view to show only items where the FolderLevelv property is 1 (i.e., top-level folders).

Default View:

This is usually the standard view for the document library showing all items, including those inside folders.
Step 2: Tag items to be level 1
e.g.
if ($folder["FileSystemObjectType"] -eq "Folder" -and $folder["FileDirRef"] -eq "/sites/yoursite/$libraryName") {
        # Set metadata or tagging if needed
        Set-PnPListItem -List $library -Identity $folder.Id -Values @{"FolderLevel"="TopLevel"}
    }

For more advanced scenarios, I would rather recommend using JavaScript or SPFx (SharePoint Framework) to customize views based on folder depth.
